# Output tuple from a list without 'for'

Tags: python, tuples

I need to output tuple from a list without `for`. Tell me please, how I can do it?

I have list of all permutation for some n:

```py
l = list(itertools.permutations(range(1, int(input()) + 1)))
```

and I need (for example, if n = 2) :

```py
1 2
2 1
```

I tried, to use `sum(l, [])`, but I have not idea, how I can do line break.

Comment: `sum(l, []),` **don't even use that**. It is needlessly inefficient (quadratic time vs linear time to flatten a sequence of lists). In any case, what exactly do you want? Why do you not want to use "for"???

Comment: Do you have a *real* reason for avoiding the `for` keyword, or is this just an artificial constraint for the sake of a programming puzzle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you get back from `itertools.permutations` is an iterator (sequence) of tuples. So if you iterate over that result, each item is a tuple. The most straightforward way you can print this data in the format you want is therefore:

```
for p in l:
    for x in p:
         print(x, end=' ')
    print()
```

But that's not one but two `for` loops. Fortunately, the inner loop is unnecessary. You can unpack the tuple using the `*` operator so `print` sees it as separate arguments:

```
for p in l:
    print(*p)
```

Now, how can we get rid of the outer `for` loop? Well, we can use some other construct that does iteration, but isn't a `for` loop.  For example, we could use `map`.

```
map(lambda p: print(*p), l)
```

In Python 2, that would be all you needed. You'd end up with a list of `None` values you didn't need, but that's "okay." I mean, it's non-optimal, but it would get you the result you seek.

In Python 3, `map()` instantiates a `map` object, and nothing actually happens until you iterate over that object, typically using a `for` loop. One way to do it without a `for` loop is with `any()`, which consumes items from the iterator until it gets to a truthy value. The items in the `map` are all falsy (the `lambda` returns `None`) so `any()` will consume all of them. "Consuming" items from the `map` object will cause your lambda to be called, thereby printing each permutation.

```
any(map(lambda p: print(*p), l))
```

If you're running this code in interactive mode, you'll get a `False` printed after the values you're looking for. That is the return value from `any()`. You can keep that from being printed by assigning it to a variable.

```
x = any(map(lambda p: print(*p), l))
```

Or by making sure the final expression evaluates to `None`, which Python won't print:

```
any(map(lambda p: print(*p), l)) or None
```

This is pretty gross. It is not good Python code. Actually, it would be bad style in just about any language. But it does the job without a `for` loop...

Comment: I cann't use 'for'(

Comment: Oh of course, how did I miss that? Added a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = list(itertools.permutations(range(1, int(input()) + 1)))
print(*l, sep='\n')

 2
 (1, 2)
 (2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple version of this without using `for` is to do a `while` loop instead:

```py
l = list(itertools.permutations(range(1, int(input()) + 1)))

i = 0
while i < len(l):
    print(l[i])
    i += 1
```

And if you want the output not as a tuple but unpacked like in your example output, you can just print the unpacked version like explained by *kindall* below like this:

```py
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    print(*l[i])
    i += 1
```